# How to remove time from object in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column with dates but the column type is object, it is not a timestamp. I want to convert the whole column so that it has the datetime format but to do this I need to first remove the time, because I only want the dates.

Example:

```
Transaction_date
07/10/2019:08:00:00 PM
07/23/2019:08:00:00 PM
3/15/2021
```

In the first two rows of the transaction_date column, I just want to keep the date and remove the time. This column is still of the type object. I want to convert it into datetime. How do I do that?

Comment: Is there a colon `:` between year and hour ?  Is it a typo or a special format ?

Comment: If it's a typo, you have to replace `':'` on `str.split` by `' '`.

Comment: We have simpler way to do this if there is no colon there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.split` to remove time and convert to datetime:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Transaction_date'].str.split(':', n=1).str[0])
0   2019-07-10
1   2019-07-23
2   2021-03-15
Name: Transaction_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note from @ThePyGuy about `n=1` to limit number of splits in output and avoid unnecessary splits.

Comment: It'd be better if you passed maxsplit parameter as well, `df['Transaction_date'].str.split(':', n=1).str[0]` to avoid unnecessary splits.

Comment: I'm totally agree. TY.

Comment: This is far better now.

Comment: Is that faster than converting to datetime and then dropping the hours/mins/secs?

Comment: The problem here is the datetime format. Note the `:` between date and time for the 2 first rows. If you just convert to datetime, it will raise an exception because the datetime format is unknown. If you specify the format of the two first row, the last line will raise an exception... The easiest method is to remove all after `:` to have the same format for all rows.

Comment: Very creative, simple, and slick solution.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a handful of date formats in your data, you could create a function that tries converting each format sequentially into a datetime via `pd.to_datetime()`. E.g. for the 2 formats in your post.

```
def convert_to_datetime(x):
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(x, format="%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S %p")
    except ValueError:
        pass
    
    try:
        return pd.to_datetime(x, format="%m/%d/%Y")
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    
    return
```

Then you could use `apply` to apply it to each row, to convert to columns into a datetime columns. Then you can take the date part directly using `.dt.date`:

```
df['TransactionDate'] = df['TransactionDate'].apply(convert_to_datetime)
df['TransactionDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TransactionDate'].dt.date)
```